# Trying to connect ldap to spring project - LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object

Tags: spring, spring-security, ldap, openldap

Im trying to get a spring project up and running with openldap on my mac.

Since openldap is installed by default on OSX im using that one and then configuring it with Apache Directory studio.

My directory looks like this:

[image: Current directory structure]

And the enty like this:

[image]

I getting an error in Eclipse when i try to login with nilsi and the right password:

```
org.springframework.ldap.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; remaining name ''
at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:174)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:306)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:259)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:606)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:524)
at org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.searchForSingleAttributeValues(SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java:173)
at org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.getGroupMembershipRoles(DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.java:215)
at org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.getGrantedAuthorities(DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.java:185)
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.loadUserAuthorities(LdapAuthenticationProvider.java:197)
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:63)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:194)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

And in the ldap console i getting the following:

```
conn=1000 fd=14 ACCEPT from IP=127.0.0.1:49474 (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
connection_get(14): got connid=1000
connection_read(14): checking for input on id=1000
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 34 contents:
op tag 0x60, time 1360507317
ber_get_next
conn=1000 op=0 do_bind
ber_scanf fmt ({imt) ber:
ber_scanf fmt (m}) ber:
>>> dnPrettyNormal: <ou=users,o=backlog>
<<< dnPrettyNormal: <ou=users,o=backlog>, <ou=users,o=backlog>
conn=1000 op=0 BIND dn="ou=users,o=backlog" method=128
do_bind: version=3 dn="ou=users,o=backlog" method=128
conn=1000 op=0 BIND dn="ou=users,o=backlog" mech=SIMPLE ssf=0
do_bind: v3 bind: "ou=users,o=backlog" to "ou=users,o=backlog"
send_ldap_result: conn=1000 op=0 p=3
send_ldap_response: msgid=1 tag=97 err=0
ber_flush2: 14 bytes to sd 14
conn=1000 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
connection_get(14): got connid=1000
connection_read(14): checking for input on id=1000
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 85 contents:
op tag 0x63, time 1360507317
ber_get_next
conn=1000 op=1 do_search
ber_scanf fmt ({miiiib) ber:
>>> dnPrettyNormal: <ou=users,o=backlog>
<<< dnPrettyNormal: <ou=users,o=backlog>, <ou=users,o=backlog>
ber_scanf fmt ({mm}) ber:
ber_scanf fmt ({M}}) ber:
=> get_ctrls
ber_scanf fmt ({m) ber:
=> get_ctrls: oid="2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.2" (noncritical)
<= get_ctrls: n=1 rc=0 err=""
conn=1000 op=1 SRCH base="ou=users,o=backlog" scope=2 deref=3 filter="(uid=nilsi)"
=> bdb_search
bdb_dn2entry("ou=users,o=backlog")
=> bdb_dn2id("o=backlog")
<= bdb_dn2id: got id=0x8
=> bdb_dn2id("ou=users,o=backlog")
<= bdb_dn2id: got id=0xa
entry_decode: "ou=users,o=backlog"
<= entry_decode(ou=users,o=backlog)
search_candidates: base="ou=users,o=backlog" (0x0000000a) scope=2
=> bdb_equality_candidates (objectClass)
=> key_read
<= bdb_index_read: failed (-30988)
<= bdb_equality_candidates: id=0, first=0, last=0
=> bdb_dn2idl("ou=users,o=backlog")
<= bdb_dn2idl: id=3 first=9 last=11
=> bdb_equality_candidates (uid)
<= bdb_equality_candidates: (uid) not indexed
bdb_search_candidates: id=-1 first=9 last=11
entry_decode: "cn=Knut Knutsson,ou=users,o=backlog"
<= entry_decode(cn=Knut Knutsson,ou=users,o=backlog)
=> bdb_dn2id("cn=knut knutsson,ou=users,o=backlog")
<= bdb_dn2id: got id=0x9
=> send_search_entry: conn 1000 dn="cn=Knut Knutsson,ou=users,o=backlog"
conn=1000 op=1 ENTRY dn="cn=knut knutsson,ou=users,o=backlog"
ber_flush2: 226 bytes to sd 14
<= send_search_entry: conn 1000 exit.
bdb_search: 10 does not match filter
entry_decode: "cn=Mathias Nordin,ou=users,o=backlog"
<= entry_decode(cn=Mathias Nordin,ou=users,o=backlog)
=> bdb_dn2id("cn=mathias nordin,ou=users,o=backlog")
<= bdb_dn2id: got id=0xb
bdb_search: 11 does not match filter
send_ldap_result: conn=1000 op=1 p=3
send_ldap_response: msgid=2 tag=101 err=0
ber_flush2: 14 bytes to sd 14
conn=1000 op=1 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
slap_listener_activate(8): 
>>> slap_listener(ldap:///)
conn=1001 fd=16 ACCEPT from IP=127.0.0.1:49475 (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
connection_get(16): got connid=1001
connection_read(16): checking for input on id=1001
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 51 contents:
op tag 0x60, time 1360507317
ber_get_next
conn=1001 op=0 do_bind
ber_scanf fmt ({imt) ber:
ber_scanf fmt (m}) ber:
>>> dnPrettyNormal: <cn=Knut Knutsson,ou=users,o=backlog>
<<< dnPrettyNormal: <cn=Knut Knutsson,ou=users,o=backlog>, <cn=knut knutsson,ou=users,o=backlog>
conn=1001 op=0 BIND dn="cn=Knut Knutsson,ou=users,o=backlog" method=128
do_bind: version=3 dn="cn=Knut Knutsson,ou=users,o=backlog" method=128
bdb_dn2entry("cn=knut knutsson,ou=users,o=backlog")
conn=1001 op=0 BIND dn="cn=Knut Knutsson,ou=users,o=backlog" mech=SIMPLE ssf=0
do_bind: v3 bind: "cn=Knut Knutsson,ou=users,o=backlog" to "cn=Knut Knutsson,ou=users,o=backlog"
send_ldap_result: conn=1001 op=0 p=3
send_ldap_response: msgid=1 tag=97 err=0
ber_flush2: 14 bytes to sd 16
conn=1001 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
connection_get(16): got connid=1001
connection_read(16): checking for input on id=1001
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 101 contents:
op tag 0x63, time 1360507317
ber_get_next
conn=1001 op=1 do_search
ber_scanf fmt ({miiiib) ber:
>>> dnPrettyNormal: <cn=Knut Knutsson,ou=users,o=backlog>
<<< dnPrettyNormal: <cn=Knut Knutsson,ou=users,o=backlog>, <cn=knut knutsson,ou=users,o=backlog>
ber_scanf fmt (m) ber:
ber_scanf fmt ({M}}) ber:
=> get_ctrls
ber_scanf fmt ({m) ber:
=> get_ctrls: oid="2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.2" (noncritical)
<= get_ctrls: n=1 rc=0 err=""
conn=1001 op=1 SRCH base="cn=Knut Knutsson,ou=users,o=backlog" scope=0 deref=3 filter="(objectClass=*)"
==> limits_get: conn=1001 op=1 self="cn=knut knutsson,ou=users,o=backlog" this="cn=knut knutsson,ou=users,o=backlog"
=> bdb_search
bdb_dn2entry("cn=knut knutsson,ou=users,o=backlog")
=> send_search_entry: conn 1001 dn="cn=Knut Knutsson,ou=users,o=backlog"
conn=1001 op=1 ENTRY dn="cn=knut knutsson,ou=users,o=backlog"
ber_flush2: 226 bytes to sd 16
<= send_search_entry: conn 1001 exit.
send_ldap_result: conn=1001 op=1 p=3
send_ldap_response: msgid=2 tag=101 err=0
ber_flush2: 14 bytes to sd 16
conn=1001 op=1 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
connection_get(16): got connid=1001
connection_read(16): checking for input on id=1001
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 34 contents:
op tag 0x42, time 1360507317
ber_get_next
ber_get_next on fd 16 failed errno=0 (Undefined error: 0)
conn=1001 op=2 do_unbind
conn=1001 op=2 UNBIND
connection_close: conn=1001 sd=16
conn=1001 fd=16 closed
connection_get(14): got connid=1000
connection_read(14): checking for input on id=1000
ber_get_next
ber_get_next: tag 0x30 len 245 contents:
op tag 0x63, time 1360507317
ber_get_next
conn=1000 op=2 do_search
ber_scanf fmt ({miiiib) ber:
>>> dnPrettyNormal: <>
<<< dnPrettyNormal: <>, <>
ber_scanf fmt ({mm}) ber:
>>> nameUIDPretty: <cn=Knut Knutsson,ou=users,o=backlog>
>>> dnPretty: <cn=Knut Knutsson,ou=users,o=backlog>
<<< dnPretty: <cn=Knut Knutsson,ou=users,o=backlog>
<<< nameUIDPretty: <cn=Knut Knutsson,ou=users,o=backlog>
>>> dnNormalize: <cn=Knut Knutsson,ou=users,o=backlog>
<<< dnNormalize: <cn=knut knutsson,ou=users,o=backlog>
ber_scanf fmt ({M}}) ber:
=> get_ctrls
ber_scanf fmt ({m) ber:
=> get_ctrls: oid="2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.2" (noncritical)
<= get_ctrls: n=1 rc=0 err=""
conn=1000 op=2 SRCH base="" scope=2 deref=3 filter="(uniqueMember=cn=knut knutsson,ou=users,o=backlog)"
conn=1000 op=2 SRCH attr=cn objectClass javaSerializedData javaClassName javaFactory javaCodeBase javaReferenceAddress javaClassNames javaRemoteLocation
send_ldap_result: conn=1000 op=2 p=3
send_ldap_response: msgid=3 tag=101 err=32
ber_flush2: 14 bytes to sd 14
conn=1000 op=2 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=32 nentries=0 text=
```

My connection to ldap looks as follows:

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/auth/login"
        access="permitAll" />

    <security:form-login login-page="/auth/login"
        authentication-failure-url="/auth/login?error=true" />

    <security:logout invalidate-session="true"
        logout-success-url="/auth/login" logout-url="/auth/logout" />

</security:http>

<security:ldap-server url="${ldap.url}"
    manager-dn="${ldap.managerdn}" manager-password="${ldap.managerpassword}" />
```

And the properties file:

```
# Ldap server settings:
ldap.url=ldap://localhost:389
ldap.managerdn=ou=users,o=backlog
ldap.managerpassword=1234
ldap.user-search-filter=(uid={0})
ldap.user-search-base=ou=users,o=backlog
```

DBD definitions in slapd.conf:

```
#######################################################################
# BDB database definitions
#######################################################################

database    bdb
suffix      "o=backlog" 
rootdn      "ou=users,o=backlog"
# Cleartext passwords, especially for the rootdn, should
# be avoid.  See slappasswd(8) and slapd.conf(5) for details.
# Use of strong authentication encouraged.
rootpw      {MD5}gdyb21LQTcIANtvYMT7QVQ==
# The database directory MUST exist prior to running slapd AND 
# should only be accessible by the slapd and slap tools.
# Mode 700 recommended.
directory   /private/var/db/openldap/backlog
# Indices to maintain
index   objectClass eq
```

However when I try login in with an account that does not exist in my ldap directory Spring is responding with a clean log and a invalid username/password response.

Also, the application shall automatically map a user with permissions if ldap returning a user that havent used the application before. So with other words, if ldap just return a id/username whatever, then it should work.

Comment: Hello, did you find the reason causing this problem ? I have the same problem, sometimes users can log in sometimes i get NameNotFound exception

Comment: Very very very poor choice of `rootdn`. It should be an entry that does *not* exist in the DIT, and you should *not* use it in the application. That account is for OpenLDAP itself. You should create an admin user with the appropriate privileges, and have the application use that account for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I have just facing with this problem. In may case the error was related with the authenthication manager. Our configuration (which work for us) is:

```
<security:authentication-manager>
            <security:ldap-authentication-provider
                    user-search-filter="(uid={0})"
                    group-search-filter="(uniqueMember={0})"
                    group-role-attribute="cn"
                    role-prefix="ROLE_">
            </security:ldap-authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

      <security:ldap-server url="ldap://172.31.7.20:389/dc=gt,dc=local"/>
```

In our case we dont need the manager-dn configuration for the ldap server because we only use authenthication and authorization but we dont modify entries from LDAP.

We are using OpenLDAP as LDAP server with the schema rfc2307bis